# C++/WinRT extension vs NuGet package

Tags: windows, visual-studio, nuget, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

Considering a C++/WinRT Visual Studio project, which one is recommended to be used between the C++/WinRT extension and the C++/WinRT NuGet package?

I currently have both installed and the project yields errors if I remove either of them.

What is the preferred setup?

The extension can be found under Extensions->Manage Extensions->Installed.
The NuGet package under the package manager.

Answer (score 0):

The NuGet package is required. It contains the code generator and the base library implementation.

The VSIX provides the project templates. It is not required to actually compile the project, but does set up all the build steps that drive the code generation. Once you have created a project, the VSIX is no longer required.

To clarify the purpose of the VSIX extension and the NuGet package, [Ryan Shepherd](https://github.com/DefaultRyan) has recently posted [a comment](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/issues/960#issuecomment-935037763). Here is the relevant excerpt:

> The bulk of C++/WinRT's functionality is provided by the [CppWinRT NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT/). This includes the cppwinrt compiler and the MSBuild logic to wire things up.
>
> The only functionality provided by the VSIX is the project templates and the debug visualizer. Those project templates create a project with a reference to the [CppWinRT NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT/).

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add a little "update"...
If you are using VS 2022, you don't need the C++/WinRT extension (VSIX); but as [IInspectable says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69547522/5012960), you do need the Nuget package.

From Microsoft's [Introduction to C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/intro-to-using-cpp-with-winrt):

> Visual Studio 2022 ships with C++/WinRT project and item templates
> built in, so that you can get started with C++/WinRT development right
> away. It also comes with Visual Studio native debug visualization
> (natvis) of C++/WinRT projected types; providing an experience similar
> to C# debugging. Natvis is automatic for debug builds. For more info,
> see Visual Studio native debug visualization for C++/WinRT.
>
> For older versions of Visual Studio, you'll want to download and
> install the latest version of the C++/WinRT Visual Studio Extension
> (VSIX) from the Visual Studio Marketplace.